# How to read just two integers from file in common lisp

Tags: file-io, common-lisp

```
(defun read-file (filename)
    (with-open-file (stream filename)
        (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
            while line
                collect line)
    )
)
```

I'm totally new to lisp so I want to read integer by integer but I have this line by line piece of code.
So I couldn't find that.

For exmp my file;

10 20

I need help .thx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, so here's a short proposition to read a file into a string, split it by whitespace, and parse each number with `parse-integer`:

```
(mapcar #'parse-integer (str:words (uiop:read-file-string "foo.txt")))
```

`uiop` comes from ASDF and is included in all major implementations, `str` is a library to quickload.

uiop also has `read-file-lines`.

Answer (score 0):

OP goal seems to be to read lines from a file, each line containing a pair of integers, and to return a list containing all of the integers read from the file.

Given an input file, `numbers.dat`:

```
10 20
30 40
50 60
70 80
90 100
```

the file can be read into a list using `read-line`:

```
CL-USER> (with-open-file (in "numbers.dat" :direction :input)
           (loop :for line := (read-line in nil)
                 :while line
                 :collect line))
("10 20" "30 40" "50 60" "70 80" "90 100" "")
```

But now the list contains strings, and each string corresponds to a pair of integers. We need a function to extract the integers from the strings. Common Lisp has the function [`read-from-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_fro.htm), which parses a string containing a printed representation of an object and returns that object and the first unread position of the input string. This function can be used in a loop to extract the integers from an input string:

```
CL-USER> (loop :with num
               :and pos := 0
               :do (setf (values num pos)
                         (read-from-string "10 20" t nil :start pos))
               :collect num
               :until (= pos 5))
(10 20)
```

If this code is removed to a function that can handle strings of varying lengths and empty strings, and mapped over an input list like `("10 20" "30 40" "50 60" "70 80" "90 100" "")`, we will be close to the goal with `((10 20) (30 40) (50 60) (70 80) (90 100) ())`. The contents of such a list could be appended together to obtain the desired list of all integers from the file:

```
;;; Expects well-behaved input
(defun get-numbers-from-string (string)
  (if (string= string "")  ; empty string returns empty list
      '()
      (let ((*read-eval* nil)  ; small precaution to guard against malicious input
            (length (length string)))
        (loop :with num      ; number from STRING
              :and pos := 0  ; next position in STRING to read from
              :do (setf (values num pos)
                        (read-from-string string t nil :start pos))
              :collect num
              :until (= pos length)))))

(defun read-integer-pairs (filename)
  (with-open-file (in filename
                      :direction :input)
    (apply #'append  ; combine sublists into a single list of numbers
           (mapcar #'get-numbers-from-string  ; transform strings to number pairs
                   (loop :for line := (read-line in nil)
                         :while line
                         :collect line)))))
```

Sample interaction:

```
CL-USER> (read-integer-pairs "numbers.dat")
(10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Read just 2 integers from a file"

leaves some room for interpretation.
I will start by answering in the most literal sense:

##### Really just 2 integers in the file

```
(defun read-2-integers (stream)
       (let ((i0 (read stream nil))
         (i1 (read stream nil)))
         (list i0 i1)))
```

If you write your functions in terms of a stream instead of a filename, you have an easier time testing interactively. For example:

```
CL-USER> (with-input-from-string (stream "10 20")
            (read-2-integers stream))
(10 20)
```

##### 2 integers *per line* in the file

Here is, where your code in the question comes in - as you would want
to read the file line by line (in case there are so many lines, that the whole file might not fit into memory or just because of other reasons).

```
(defun read-lines-with-2-integers (stream)
       (loop
         for line = (read-line stream nil)
         while line
         collecting (with-input-from-string (line-stream line)
              (read-2-integers line-stream))))
```

Let's test if it works:

```
CL-USER> (with-input-from-string (stream "10 20
30 40
50 60")
           (read-lines-with-2-integers stream))
((10 20) (30 40) (50 60))
```

##### Lines with integers in the file

```
;; first, we replace our function "read-2-integers" with something a bit more general, so we can apply it to a single line:
(defun read-integers (stream)
       (loop 
         for c = (peek-char t stream nil) ;; skips whitespace
         while c
         collecting (read stream nil)))
;; next, we use this function just like we used "read-2-integers" before:
(defun read-lines-with-integers (stream)
       (loop 
         for line = (read-line stream nil)
         while line
         collecting 
         (with-input-from-string (line-stream line)
           (read-integers line-stream))))
```

which we can test like so:

```
CL-USER> (with-input-from-string (stream "10 20
30 40 50
60 70
80")
           (read-lines-with-integers stream))
((10 20) (30 40 50) (60 70) (80))
```

##### File with integers - lines do not matter

In this case, we can just use our `read-integers` function from above:

```
CL-USER> (with-input-from-string (stream "10 
20
30 40")
       (read-integers stream))
(10 20 30 40)
```